# ¿Cómo desplegar todos los elementos de un array, con laravel Vue js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, html5, vue.js

estoy trabajando con Laravel y Vue Js, y estoy realizando un post para que me traiga unos valores array desde la base de datos, la respuesta al query sería este tipo de array (ejemplo):

```html
let response = {};
    response.data = [
     {
     plataforma: "[\"Facebook\", \"Youtube\",\"Instagram\",\"LinkedIn\"]"
     }
    ];
```

La definición en Axios Post sería así:

```html
   
    let me = this;
    axios.post('/url', const).then(function(response){      
       $.each(response.data, function (key,value) {
            $.each(JSON.parse( value.estilo ), (key,element) => { 
              me.plataformas.push(element);
            });
       });
    });
```

Hasta ahí asumo todo bien, porque al revisar el `console.log(me.plataformas);` , me entrega esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero noto que genera una instancia por cada elemento del array, entonces al momento de enviarlo a html, me está trayendo sólo el último elemento, que en este caso viene siendo `LinkedIn`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="row-md-6">
     <div class="form-group m-3">
        <label>Seleccione las opciones de tu Servicio:</label>
          <div class="col-6">
             <div class="m-3" v-for="plataforma in plataformas" :key="plataforma.id">
                 {{plataforma}}                                  
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>  
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Hay algo que deba agregar a mi código?

Comment: Ahora está modificado correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro, pero a simple vista pienso que tu error es que sobreescribes el valor de `me.plataformas = element` en cada iteración. Lo ideal sería que lo trates como un array e insertes los valores así:

```
me.plataformas.push(element)
```

Luego lo renderizas en la plantilla así:

```
  <div class="m-3" v-for="plataforma in plataformas" :key="plataforma.id">
                 {{plataforma.key}}                                  
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola Joel, gracias por tu respuesta.. la verdad realicé la modificación pero no me está trayendo nada. lo hice de esta manera 
$.each(response.data, function (key,value) {
            me.plataformas.push(value.plataforma)
        });
});

Comment: Actualiza tu codigo para revisar

Comment: Ahora está modificado

Comment: plataforma.id y plataforma.key te los puse como ejemplo. Estos deben ser reemplazados según la estructura de tu objeto o arreglo.

Comment: Haz un console.log(key) y console.log(value) para ver que contienen

Comment: en console.log(key) me da =  0, console.log(value) me da = {id: 1, idTiposervicio: 1, estilo: "["Facebook", "Youtube", "Instagram", "LinkedIn"]", created_at: null}

Comment: ya lo solucioné, como mencionaste que había que tratar el array, había quitado el  foreach que genera el parse, lo cual al agregarlo, con el push me está trayendo todos los valores, sin necesidad de sobreescribirlo por cada iteración, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

en vue se utilizar diferentes una sixtaxis mucho mas simple, aqui hay un ejemplo mas simple y mucho mas funcional

primero hay que declara las varibles en vue, si no lo hace el codigo no va a funcional bien en el array data ref:1

en la variables datos_social representa los datos en la referencia 2, los datos tiene el formato Json

en la referencia 3 se utiliza el this.  =>  this.datos_social , para reemplazar los datos

mounted() se utiliza para llamar la funcion al inicio

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { //referencia 1
    datos:[],
    datos_social:[ //referencia 2
        {nombre:'facebock',id:1},
        {nombre:'twiter',id:2}
    ],
    
  },
  mounted() {
       this.consulta();
  },
  methods: {
    consulta(){
     axios.post("url", data).then(response => {
            const data = response.data;
            this.datos_social = response.data //referencial 3
})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>redes sociales:</h2>
  <span v-for='data in datos_social' v-bind:key='data.id'>
      {{data.id}} -
      {{data.nombre}}
  
  </span>
  
</div>
```

mientras que en laravel utilizo la siguiente funcio para retorma los datos en formato Json

```
$data=Orden_Servicion_KitModel::all();

return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: Está bien lo que mencionas, pero si notas.. estoy intentando renderizar el atributo plataforma que posee un array, el ejemplo que mencionas estás trayendo un objeto que posee el atributo nombre e id. No es lo mismo.

Comment: ya termine con las solución, por parte de laravel y vue

Comment: Hice lo que modificaste trayendo el valor como json, ahora cuando traigo dentro del v-for, traigo {{data.plataforma}} , me lo trae como un array ["Facebook", "Youtube", "Instagram", "LinkedIn"], y es lo que te decía, necesito realizar otra acción más para renderizarlo eso como lista.

Comment: en la base de datos siempre lo trae como json, pero si lo esta trayendo como un array no les va a imprimir igual en vez de eso deber declara la variable como Json $data=[ {nombre:"facebook"} , { nombre:"twiter" }  ];